# mount one of two devices depending on presence

Tags: mount

I have a mobile computer which is, when in one of two places, connected to a hard disk. I would like to mount the hard disk, when present, at the same mount point; i.e. one or the other disk (never are both present) is mounted at the same location. I use at the moment two lines in the fstab

```
/dev/santafe-vg/additionalSpaceToSSD /home/frank/additionalSpaceLV ext4 defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=9 0 0
/dev/london-vg/additionalSpaceAF /home/frank/additionalSpaceLV ext4 defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=9 0 0
```

Which seem to work, but the solution does not convince me. What is the best solution?

Comment: What's wrong with the way you're doing it?

Comment: You can use systemd or udev, see https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html or https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Mounting_drives_in_rules. I would not touch `/etc/fstab` in this topic.

Comment: Please add distro tag, thx.

Comment: I looked into your valuable suggestions but have the impression, that it will force a combination of udev rules (to mount the device) and systemd path is complicated (and with complex potential interactions). Do you know of an example to follow?

Comment: The current solution leads to a long wait (1min30 time-out) when booting  - despite the timeout set. Why is the `device-timeout` not effective?